# Get cluster's name / details of a server where your app [MULE API] is deployed

Tags: java, api, amazon-web-services, mule, cluster-computing

I would like to get the cluster name of the production server where my app [Mulesoft api] is deployed.   The server, I do think, is an AWS VM instance.

I do have the IP Address, but I guess I would have to ask for the credentials in order to query this details?

Cheers guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [official documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/mule-expression-language-reference) the mule context object has attributes `clusterId` and `nodeId`. Please try `#[mule.clusterId]` or `#[mule.nodeId]` and let me know if it works.

Comment: Inside of a MEL expression? .. I thought it was more of a 'muleContext.getClusterdId()'

Comment: both should work, because there is a `getInstanceId()` in [MuleContext](https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.3.0/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleContext.html) too.